# BigQuery - How to exclude unrepeatable struct fields

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I run into an error trying to exclude unrepeatable struct fields,

Here is an example:

```
select * except( test.attr1 ) 
from ( select struct( attr1, attr2 ) as test
    from ( select 'a' attr1, 'b' attr2 ))
```

I am getting the syntax error below.

> ### Error running query
>
> Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "." at [1:21]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use REPLACE instead (note: I added one more field into struct  - just so example is more presentative)

```
select * replace(
  (select as struct * except(attr1) from unnest([test])) as test
) 
from ( select struct( attr1, attr2, attr3 ) as test
    from ( select 'a' attr1, 'b' attr2, 'c' attr3 ))
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

`EXCEPT` works on columns, not on fields in structs.  But you can do what you want by using a subquery to select the structure as columns and then removing the column you want:

```
 with t as (
       select 1 as x, t.*
       from ( select struct( attr1, attr2 ) as test
              from ( select 'a' attr1, 'b' attr2 )
            ) t
       )
select t.* except (test),
       (select test.* except (attr2)
        from (select as value test 
              from t
             ) test
       ) test_minus_attr2
from t;
```

I added `x` as an arbitrary column simply because `t.* except (test)` will not work if it selects no columns.  You can leave it out if you just want the struct.

Comment: Nice try, but it is too cumbersome.

Comment: @ronencozen . . . I'm not sure what that is supposed to mean.  This answers the question you have asked.  It is exactly one subquery more than the query in your question.